# Purpose of this resistor in a low-pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, low-pass

I found this filter configuration on one of older soundcards:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI8yek.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V1 here is the DAC output with a positive voltage offset.
What is the purpose of the R3 resistor? Is it added to reduce common mode noise in the output? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: If Vsine is not used (no input), input is grounded ... with reduction of amplification.

Comment: @Antonio51, Vsine is the output of a DAC chip. It has positive offset which is removed using a 10uF capacitor. Then this filter circuit follows. I updated the circuit to include the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

Without \$R_3\$ (and ignoring \$C_2\$ for a moment) the gain equation from op amp's output to the signal input would be

$$
G=\frac{V_o}{V_i}=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{R_1C_1}}
$$

But with \$R_3\$, it'd be

$$
G=\frac{V_o}{V_i}=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{s}{s+\frac{R_1+R_3}{R_1R_3C_1}}
$$

So the mid-band gain is still the same for both but the latter's cut-off frequency is higher than the first one's (twice, since \$R_1=R_3\$).

> Is it added to reduce common mode noise in the output?

The idea behind adding \$R_3\$ can't be anything related to filtering because reducing \$C_1\$ would be more than enough to push the cut-off frequency forward whilst keeping the mid-band gain the same.

So the only thing I can think of is **to shunt the input to the ground via a low enough resistance** so the amplifier doesn't produce noise (although the gain is low) in case of a disappearance of the input source (failure/malfunction of DAC) which means a floating input to a high impedance.

---

Adding \$R_3\$ increases the loading of the DAC. Because, at mid-band frequencies, the DAC will see the entire amplifier section as a resistor connected to ground. Without R3 this would be \$R_1=12k\Omega\$ but with \$R_3\$ this is now \$R_1 || R_3=6k\Omega\$ because right-side terminal of \$R_1\$ is virtually connected to the ground making \$R_1\$ and \$R_3\$ in parallel. This probably will not hurt the DAC but effectively increases the loading.

Comment: This sound card does not seem to have any mute switches on output. Could this be a workaround to prevent noise or hum on outputs when the input suddenly becomes floating?

Comment: @bkxp yes, that is what I said above starting with the bold text. I don't know if the input can suddenly be floating as it comes from a DAC. But this doesn't change the main idea and result.